# How to remove the dot in the milliseconds value in time.Format

Tags: go, time

I want to produce a time with this specific format in Go using the time.Format function:

```
yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS    // SSS == milliseconds
```

Following the [documentation](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go), I got to this point (using stdFracSecond0):

```
format := "2006_01_02_15_04_05_.000"
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(format))
```

Which outputs:

```
2021_06_18_10_21_19_.179
```

**How can I remove the dot before the milliseconds value?**

This does not work (millis are always zero):

```
format := "2006_01_02_15_04_05_000"
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hE-95YuCvPa) example

Comment: `format := "2006_01_02_15_04_05_.000"
 fmt.Println(strings.Replace(time.Now().Format(format), `_.`, `_`, 1))`

Comment: Are you trying to parse a timestamp in that format, or you're trying to produce a timestamp in that format?

Comment: I am trying to produce it from server time.

Comment: Thanks. I updated your question to remove the word "parse", then, since that made it confusing.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the dot before milliseconds use `strings.Replace()` method .Please find the code below with the same logic .

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    format := "2006_01_02_15_04_05_.000"
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(format))
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace(time.Now().Format(format), "_.", "_", 1))

}
```

Output:

```
2009_11_10_23_00_00_.000
2009_11_10_23_00_00_000
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `strings.Replace()` to remove `.` from your formatted time string.

```
strings.Replace(time.Now().Format(format), `.`, ``, 1)
```

[run here](https://play.golang.org/p/HMf62JsT-BC)

Comment: Although it is workaround and it's not safe/performant, it's just one line, which is good in terms of readability. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`do` function efficiently removes the `.` (dot) from the format.

As per the format's convention, a decimal point followed by one or more zeros represents a fractional second, printed to the given number of decimal places.
Hence, using the same is safe (eg. `.000` instead of `.999`).

The `do` function does some sanity check so that format is not valid.

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

// do replaces the dot (.) with underscore (_) safely
func do(t string) (string, error) {
    // size is the expected length of the string
    const size = 24
    if tLen := len(t); tLen != size {
        return "",
            fmt.Errorf(
                "invalid format size: expected %d, got %d", size, tLen,
            )
    }

    if t[size-4] != '.' {
        return "", errors.New("invalid format")
    }

    // Use strings.Builder for concatenation
    sb := strings.Builder{}
    sb.Grow(size)
    // For: "2006_01_02_15_04_05_.000"
    // Join "2006_01_02_15_04_05_" and "000"
    sb.WriteString(t[0 : size-4])
    sb.WriteString(t[size-3 : size])

    return sb.String(), nil
}

func main() {
    format := "2006_01_02_15_04_05_.000"
    t, err := do(time.Now().Format(format))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this is too complex. But IMO the biggest problem is that is not extensible. The method has to be adaptaded every time the format changes, thus it would hurt the mainteinability of the code.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But it's safe. Maybe you can get rid of those errors checks and just keep the `strings.Builder`